# How to find total quantity of green crosses in images

Tags: python, image-processing, histogram

Working with an image processing project to find all green (128) crosses from multiple images.

[image: 1]

Should achieve the following:

1. total amount of image files
2. Count the ones with less/most amount of crosses in image file including names of the files with it.
3. The mean of the crosses and total amount of the crosses.
4. Histogram over the distribution of the number of plus.

The crosses should at least look like this, meaning two crosses can be next to each other. Should count all crosses (inculding copies). The white boxes outside the cross can have various colors

[image: 2]

In the left picture below are 2 crosses and in the right you will find four (there are other variants than the two below):

[image: 3]

Quite new to all this so thanks in advance, this is what I have to go on:

```py
from PIL import Image

import numpy as np

im = Image.open("testbild.bmp")

M = np.asarray(im)


def antalkors(M):

    kors = 0
    for i in range(2,M.shape[0]-2):
        for j in range(2,M.shape[1]-2):
            if M[i][j] == 128 and M[i][j-1] == 128 and M[i][j-2]==128 and M[i][j+1] == 128 and M[i][j+2] == 128 and M[i-1][j] == 128 and M[i-2][j] == 128 and M[i+1][j] == 128 and M[i+2][j] == 128:
                  kors += 1
        return kors
```

Comment: what makes those crosses? is the information of those positions available in any other form? be specific, very specific. -- work through official documentation tutorials of OpenCV and/or scikit-image.

Comment: Sorry about that, the information I have to go on is: The images are stored in an uncompressed bmp format (bitmap), where the images have the size 760 x 580. Each pixel takes one byte. The format uses indexed color.

Comment: I'm asking _what application made those_. you can possibly avoid having to scrape this information out of pictures when it's available in other forms that are more convenient. if you don't have that information, perhaps ask everyone who might know someone who might know. -- if you really really have to, just apply opencv's template matching. that's basically convolution/correlation, except it's not fourier-based, so the template/kernel can have a mask of valid pixels too. I'd recommend the `TM_SQDIFF` mode

Comment: The green cross just above and to the right of the centre appears to be thicker but it is hard to tell at the given resolution. Is it the case that there are two crosses right on top of one another and are you supposed to be able to detect that and do you have a full resolution image to share?

Comment: Will try Christoph, for you Mark. For some crosses there might be two crosses on top or next to each other, should count these at seperate crosses, can upload image to show what I mean

Answer (score 1):

As a first step, I would load the image and make a mask of where the green pixels are so that I just had one channel rather than three to deal with, and to speed up processing:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

# Load image as BGR
im = cv2.imread('iejDj.png', cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)

# Now make a single channel image that is 255 where green and black elsewhere:
green = np.all(im==[0,255,0], axis=2) * 255
```

That looks like this:

[image]

Next, make a template along these lines:

```
template = np.zeros((5,5), np.uint8)
template[2,:] = 255
template[:,2] = 255
```

That looks like this:

[image]

Then follow Christoph's advice and use OpenCV [Template Matching](https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/d4/dc6/tutorial_py_template_matching.html).